# How can I sort unordered points into an clock-wise ordered list?

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have 4 nodes that are vertices of quadrilateral.

I need to sort these vertices clockwise or contour clockwise. In MATLAB I know just function ispolycw

that does not work true, when it is not sorted clockwise this function returns 1.

Is there anyone who know a function (or any suggestion )that  I could  sort these vertices?

I am grateful to you for your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a function to do this once. I don't have the code handy, but the basic approach was this:

1. find the center of gravity C of the points
2. find direction from C to each point
3. get the direction as an angle from 0 to 2*pi
4. sort

So if the points are P(4, 2):

```
C = sum(P) / size(P, 1);
dv = bsxfun(@minus, P, C);
a = atan2(dv(:,2), dv(:,1)) + pi;
[s si] = sort(a);
sortedVertices = P(si, :);
```

I can't test this right now but I think that's right (or close).

Comment: Brilliant! I think `atan2(dv(2,:), dv(1,:))` should be `atan2(dv(:,2), dv(:,1))`. Just in case you are not aware, you can [compile this online](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php) when you don't have access to matlab.

Comment: Sorry, I check it but it returns just the first and second rows of P.

Comment: @Rosa Try with my edit. It worked for me. It's just that Floris couldn't test it and indices order were not proper.

Comment: I should  say sorry again. Maybe my define of clockwise sort is not true. I need to sort P so that plot of P returns a figure like quadrilateral and no like butterfly. Could you help me for this, Please?

Comment: @jkshah thanks for the edit. Rosa - I will take another look when I get to a computer (not my phone...)

Comment: @Rosa - can you give an example of "butterfly"? What vertices, how you used the above code, and the plot command you used?